# How to get running scene class type in Cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, appdelegate

In **Cocos2d** i use to get my current running scene through the code:

```
CCScene *runningScene = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene];
    if ([runningScene isKindOfClass:[GameScene class]])
```

Is there any similar method to get this on **cocos2d-x** also???

I am using:

```
CCScene *scene = (CCScene *)CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getRunningScene();
```

but how to compare it with current scene??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dynamic cast` which returns pointer of given type or returns NULL value.

```
CCScene *scene = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getRunningScene();    
GameScene* gameScene = dynamic_cast<GameScene*>(scene);    
if(gameScene != NULL)
{
   // scene is type of GameScene
}
```

Comment: I have a strange situation here. I do exactly what you have suggested to assert it the scene is the one I need. Assertion fails, as `dynamic_cast` results to `NULL` pointer. I'm on Android and RTTI flag is on. I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: It should never happen. Make sure assert always executes when condition goes wrong. Share code block if possible.

Comment: Agree, it should not happen. Here is my code:
`DecorationScene* decorationScene = dynamic_cast<DecorationScene*>(Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene());
assert(decorationScene != NULL && "Popup is called only form Decoration scene.");`

Comment: @Narek did you find a solution to your problem ? I also always get only a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic_cast, but you must pay attention to the difference between CCLayer and CCScene.
GameScene is type CCLayer, I guess.
So if you write the following code, you can not get the hopeful result.

```
GameScene *gameScene = dynamic_cast<GameScene*>(scene);
```

scene is type `CCScene`, and `GameScene` is type `CCLayer`. You must do as followings.

**

```
CCScene *scene = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getRunningScene();
CCLayer *layer = (CCLayer*)(scene->getChildren()->objectAtIndex(0));
GameScene *gameScene = dynamic_cast<GameScene*>(layer);
```

**

if `GameScene` is inherited from other customized Layer, e.g., `MyLayer`, you should change `CCLayer` with `MyLayer`.